# subtracting time for date time in SQL Developer

Tags: datetime, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQL Developer (3.1.06) to pull information from DWHP. I want to subtract time (hh:mm:ss)--> timecol_3 from date time (dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss)-->datetime_col4, so that something like 
(10/01/15 01:00:00)-(03:00:00) should display (09/01/15 22:00:00).

Now the date time wasnt combined intially and neither were they in the above format. (they were in mm/dd/yyyy and hhmmA or hhmmP format), So I used the following syntax to bring it to the (dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss) format-->

**to_char(to_date(datecol_1 || ' ' || timecol2, 'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi:ss'), 'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi:ss') as datetime_col4**

Could you please help??

Comment: I'm not really following the question.  I assume DWHP is some acronym for a data warehouse that you've built or that you're using.  I'm guessing that you are saying that `datecol_1` and `timecol2` are `varchar2` columns in the format "mm/dd/yy" and "hhmmA" respectively.  You want to convert `datecol_1` to a date, convert `timecol2` to an interval, subtract the two, and then convert the result to a `varchar2` in the format `dd/mm/yy hh24:mi:ss`.  Is that right?  Why are you storing the values in the wrong data type to begin with?  Why is your example adding the time to the date?

Comment: @JustinCave So the idea is to get the dates and time in the format I want first, ie, in dd/mm/yy hh24:mi:ss and display it in say col_1. Now I have another column (say col_2) that has time in hh24:mi:ss. I want to subtract col_2 from col_1.

Comment: @JustinCave
So, to answer your question. I want to combine datecol_1 and timecol_2 in one single column and then subtract a new timecol_3 from it. 
To combine this date and time column, I used the syntax I wrote in my question. 
It seemed to work fine. Not sure if its a string or in datetime format. I think its in datetime format since I specified 'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi:ss' at the end. Let me know if this is correct at all!

Comment: What is the data type of `datecol_1`?  What is the data type of `timecol2`?  What is the desired data type of `datetime_col4`?  If the system were designed properly, it would appear that `datecol_1` and `datetime_col4` should each be a `date` while `timecol2` should be an interval.  But it doesn't appear that you're using the proper data types.

Comment: Ok. 
Datecol_1 --> dd/mm/yy

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help.  "dd/mm/yy" isn't a data type.  `date` is a data type.  But a `date` does not have a format.  `varchar2` is a data type.  A string representing a date would need to be stored in a particular format.  That's the wrong way to store a date but it wouldn't be hugely uncommon particularly in a data warehouse.  `number` is also a data type and people sometimes use that to store numbers that represent dates though that is also the wrong way to store a date.

Comment: @JustinCave Sorry for the confusion. I guess, I wasn't able to frame my question properly. 
Ok. 
Datecol_1 --> 11-Jun-2015
timecol_2 --> hhmmA for AM and  hhmmP for PM

Desired datetime_col4 --> dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss

And from this subtract time (timecol_3) which is in format --> hhmm (which looks like a number)  
.................What I tried to do was, get datecol_1 in dd/mm/yy format, timecol_2 in hh:mm:ss format, and change timecol_3 in hh:mm:ss format. Then, concatenate datecol_1 and timecol_2  into datetime_col4 and try to subtract timecol_3 from datetime_col4. ....was replicating Excel !!

Comment: I dont know what the data type is for these columns

Comment: Step 1 is going to be to look at the database and tell us what data types your columns are and what data type you want to return.

Comment: @JustinCave Ok. So datecol_1 --> DATE --> 13-Feb-15. Timecol_2 -->CHAR-->0907P . Timecol_3--> NUMBER-->0530. Desired output format for datetime_col4 -->DATETIME--> mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss

Comment: I think What I did with all these data tyoes so far is convert them into CHAR. Not sure if that was a good idea in the very first place. I have all these columns in the format that I need but everything is in CHAR now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data is in string format (based on the manipulations performed in your bolded text):

> **to_char(to_date(datecol_1 || ' ' || timecol2, 'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi:ss'), 'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi:ss') as datetime_col4**

In oracle it's best to work with dates in the native date type rather than constantly converting them to and from character data types, so datetime_col4 would be better represented like so:

```
to_date(datecol_1 || ' ' || timecol2, 'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi:ss') as datetime_col4
```

Now assuming timecol_3 is a character string also in the hh24:mi:ss form where the hh24 portion ranges between 00 and 23, you can cast timecol_3 to an interval data type (the closest data type oracle has to a pure time data type) like so:

```
cast('0 '||timecol_3 as interval day to second) timecol3
```

You need the leading '0 ' when casting to an interval to represent the day portion of the interval, in this case zero days.

Interval data types can be added and subtracted to and from each other and to and from date[time] data types natively in oracle, so to get your final result as a date date type (starting from your base columns):

```
  to_date(datecol_1 || ' ' || timecol2, 'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi:ss')
- cast('0 '||timecol_3 as interval day to second) result
```

You can wrap that with a final to_char() to display the results in your desired format, or change your NLS_DATE_FORMAT session setting to output all date data types in your desired format:

```
ALTER SESSION NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS';
```